# Can the orientation of objects emitted from a particle system be controlled?

Tags: particles

When emitting objects from a particle system (boids) the objects appear with random orientation, while they move it would look much nicer if e.g. a spacecrafts nose would point into flight direction.

It seems to have a leader at the first position of the *Boids Brain* panel helps but then the particle tend to clump, when separation is added they start to move with random orientation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mesh should be rotated in *Edit Mode* so that the nose points into the emitting direction, then the will always point to the flight direction.

[image]

The rules to prevent clumping:

[image]

Comment: And the mesh should be such that "forward" is the positive (local, if the object containing the mesh is rotated) Y axis.